# How to show a dialog inside a form inside a form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, backgroundworker

**I want to**

1) On my main window I have Form1

2) I have a backgroundworker looking for something specific to happen

3) When something specific happens, I want to "blur" the whole screen, so I spawn a new BlurForm inside the backgroundworker (this works)

4) And additionally, ON this BlurForm, I want a Dialog where the user puts his name and age.

**My Problems:**

1) Either the "blur" goes away immediately after calling the dialog

2) The whole application "freezes"

**My code:**

MyBackgroundWorker.cs

```
var blurrer = new BlurForm(_parent) // _parent is Form1 (main Form)
blurrer.ShowSpecificDialog(new MyData(){...});
```

BlurForm.cs

```
public BlurForm(Form owner){
   _owner = owner;
   Initialize(owner); // Set width, color etc.
   Show();  // Default method to show.
}

public DialogResult ShowSpecificDialog(MyData data){
   var dialog = new MyDialog(this, data); // this = parent-form of the dialog
   return dialog.ShowDialog(_owner);
}
```

What now happens is, that the BlurForm shows (screen is blurred as I wished), the Dialog shows (but it is "covered" by the blur as well (why?)) and the screen "freezes" (I think the blur "blocks"). As soon as I take the focus out of the BlurForm, it "unblocks", goes away and the dialog is shown clearly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i would suggest not popping up a dialog like that.  it makes the user feel out of control in the app.  instead i would show some sort of indicator on the main form that there is something new come in.  a bit like a new mail icon or something. this has the added advantage that the user can decide when to look at the message and you simply handle the event when the user clicks the mew message icon

Comment: Hi john, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, the dialog is a "error-dialog", so the user MUST see and resolve it, not optional

Comment: would have been nice to know that before i answered - good luck!

Comment: I think this may be an threading issue, because you wrote application is freezing. Please check if the new dialog/blur window is opened in the gui thread of your main form.

Comment: Seems like something is wrong with the BlurForm...